# Comparing two dimensional arrays to one another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, format

I want to write a code where it outputs the similarities for the values of arrays `a,b,c`. I want the code to check if there are any similar values between the arrays. I will be comparing `b and c` to `a`. So `[         0, 1624580882]` exist when comparing `a` and `b` and so on. Both the columns must be equivalent for the comparison to work.

```
import numpy as np 

a= np.array([[         0, 1624580882],
 [         1, 1624584458],
 [         0, 1624589467],
 [         1, 1624592213],
 [         0, 1624595336],
 [         1, 1624596349]])

b= np.array([[         1, 1624580882],
 [         1, 1624584460],
 [         1, 1624595336],
 [         1, 1624596349]])


c = np.array([[         0, 1624580882],
 [         1, 1624584458],
 [         0, 1624589495],
 [         1, 1624592238],
 [         0, 1624595336],
 [         1, 1624596349]])
```

Expected Output:

```
b comparison
Similarities= None

c comparison
Similarities= [         0, 1624580882],[         1, 1624584464], [         0, 1624595350],[         1, 1624596380]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Both the columns must be equivalent for the comparison to work"?

Comment: so the first columns are 0s and 1s and the second columns contains the large integer vals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not giving you the actual solution rather I can help you with a simple function. You can design the rest of your code according to that function.

```
def compare_arrays(arr_1, arr_2):
    result = []
    for row in arr_1:
        result.append(row in arr_2)
    return result
```

**Edit:**

For getting the index of the duplicate values.

```
 from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn
 ndtype = [('a', int)]
 a = np.ma.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],mask=[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]).view(ndtype)
 rfn.find_duplicates(a, ignoremask=True, return_index=True)
```

Comment: is there a way I could just have the index of the arrays that are equivalent. So that I do not have to append them to a list

Comment: yes, but it won't give you your desired output. It will return only the boolean values. If you are an expert on this you can extract the index and implement it in your code. See the edited answer in section edit for the indexing. @georgehere

Answer (score 1):

not the most beautiful solution. But the first thing that comes to mind:

```py
result = []
for row in a:
    for irow in c:
        if np.all(np.equal(row, irow)):
            result.append(row)
            break
```

I note that the proposed by `Fatin Ishrak Rafi` solution does not work. For example:

```py
>>> [0, 1624589467] in c
>>> True
```